# Validate password reset token without email/userid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I would like to verify that reset password link is expired before user enters any data (email, new password). There is a method `VerifyUserTokenAsync` that validates tokens but it requires `user` parameter.

Is it a good idea to append UserId to the password reset link?

Comment: It could open the door for a bad actor to masquerade as another user and reset his/her password. You can, however, sign a JWT, add just the user id claim and append it to the reset link. 
You only need to check if it's really signed by you for that particular user.

Comment: @abdusco, actually I think it safe to simply append expiration information to the token e.g. via query param because token validation is still in place.

Comment: True. JWT even requires you to declare a valid timeframe where the token is valid (using `nbf` and `exp` claims).